# access address lookup table on chain

Tags: solana-program

decoding address lookup table data are in solana-address-lookup-table-program. However, that depends on "solana-sdk", which pulls in a lot and doesn't work with programs.

Answer (score 1):

`solana-address-lookup-table-program` only depends on `solana-sdk` in off-chain builds. Otherwise, it only depends on `solana-program`, which is available on-chain.

If you're seeing an issue, be sure to build with the newer Solana CLI (1.14 or newer), and try `cargo build-sbf` if `cargo build-bpf` is failing.

Here are the Cargo.toml lines: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/9746eb2c8d171b41704a7754c5da1c6d8ca101d1/programs/address-lookup-table/Cargo.toml#L24-L26